# how to change timer settings from a sub form for a main form in c#

Tags: c#

I have a timer function within my main app which acts as a timed session. However, I want to change the timer interval and an ability to turn it on and off via the sub form, but cannot use the timer functions elements within another form to change the settings. Below is my code snippet. Any tips or example will be appreciated.

Attempt : 
 **Main Form**

```
private void Booyaa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BooyaaTimer.Interval = 45 * 60 * 1000); // 45 mins
            BooyaaTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(BooyaaTimer_Tick);
            BooyaaTimer.Start();
            if (!Properties.Settings.Default.SettingShutdown)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not properly shut down");
                GetPass pass = new GetPass();
                DialogResult result = pass.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK) { 

                    Properties.Settings.Default.SettingShutdown = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
             else
            {
                Close();
            }
             }

private void BooyaaTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TIME IS UP");

            GetPass pass = new GetPass();
                DialogResult result = pass.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                Show();
                Properties.Settings.Default.SettingShutdown = true;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
                else
            {

                BooyaaTimer.Start();
                Properties.Settings.Default.SettingShutdown = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                Hide();
            }

            }
```

**Timer controls form**

```
    public object BooyaaTimer { get; private set; }



            private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


BooyaaTimer.Interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); // gives error on interval 

            }
```

Comment: The `btn_confirm_Click` code is incomplete.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp my point is that I cannot continue it, as I'm unable to use the interval functions from the main form.

Comment: What is `Timer`? And why is `BooyaaTimer` an `object` and not a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object? Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry i copied the wrong code, have look now

Comment: It doesn't answer my 2nd question. Is there a `BooyaaTimer` member object in the main form class? If so you need to pass that to the dialog class somehow.  Creating an `object BooyaaTimer` is not correct.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if you have a look at the main form BooyaaTimer is created within it via the toolbox and drag option, I've just used the object to get set the timer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a guess. The Timer is created in the main form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    Timer BooyaaTimer = new Timer(); // Or this is created in Designer

    void SomeFunctionThatCreatesTheOtherForm() {
        TimerControlsForm form2 = new TimerControlsForm();
        // Pass the timer to form2
        form2.BooyaTimer = BooyaTimer;
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And the other form

```
public partial class TimerControlsForm : Form {
    // This has to be a Timer object
    public Timer BooyaTimer {get; set;}

    private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        BooyaaTimer.Interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have managed to work around the error via :   public static System.Windows.Forms.Timer BooyaaTimer { get; internal set;} but i still get a exception at BooyaaTimer.Interval = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text); when i enter the number and press the btn_confirm

Comment: Unhandled exception

Comment: But what is the exception? Why are you using `static` and `internal` for the variable?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in BooyaaBrowser.exe

Comment: I wrote a small test app with this code and it worked fine. Your issue must lie elsewhere.